# How do I call 2 API in parallel and the third right after that in RXJS?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I want to make 2 API calls in Parallel and then the third immediately after that.
I am able to run API calls in Parallel using merge map and consecutively using concatMap. I want to combine the two.

```
//Call API1 and API2 in Parallel
// from([apiCall(1), apiCall(2)]).pipe(
//   mergeMap(e=>e)
// ).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

//Call API1 and API2 consecutively
// from([apiCall(1), apiCall(2)]).pipe(
//   concatMap(e=>e)
// ).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

//Call API1 and API2 in Parallel and API 3 right after both finishes
from([apiCall(1), apiCall(2), apiCall(3)]).pipe(
  // ????
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

How can I do such?

Stackblitz playground here => https://stackblitz.com/edit/playground-rxjs-263xwk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` for parallel requests.

```
forkJoin([apiCall(1), apiCall(2)]).pipe(
 concatMap((response) => apiCall(3).pipe(
  map((res) => [...response, res])
 ))
).subscribe((response) => {
 response[0]; // result from apiCall(1)
 response[1]; // result from apiCall(2)
 response[2]; // result from apiCall(3)
})
```

Comment: I think that `concatMap` is more idiomatic than `switchMap` when it comes to dealing with http calls, specifically in cases of POST/PUT. But apart this the response is right.

Comment: Thank you but in this case it does not emit results of apiCall(1) and apiCall(2) in subscribe

Comment: @user1034912 for passing results apiCall(1/2) to subscribe you can use ```map``` operator in nested ```concatMap```. Example: 
```
forkJoin([apiCall(1), apiCall(2)]).pipe(
      concatMap((response) => apiCall(3).pipe(
        map((res) => [...response, res])
      ))
    )
```

Comment: Thank you again. I have updated stackblitz to showcase your answer.